# Getting Warning Application should not provide its own Splash Screen in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have recently changed my Target SDK Version to 31 (Android 12) and after upgrading I started getting this warning:

> The application should not provide its own launch screen.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Is there any better approach to create Splash Screens?

**NOTE:**
I know it is just a warning and can be ignored but I'm asking for now recommended way to create Splash Screens.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

There is better approach now. For Android 12, there is brand new Splash Screen Api which works on previous versions aswell, see more [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen)

It supports theming, custom animations and is super simple to use.

Comment: You can also use the AndroidX library to help with the implementation on older devices. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/package-summary

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach with 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen' works only from 21 APIs

Comment: I am a bit confused why the website from developer android say that starting from but @TimKruichkov say works from 21 API ...  ,  so minSDK=21 targetSDK =32 works ?

Comment: I am not happy to write that, but it should not be an accepted answer, as Splash Screen Api is doubtfully "better" approach. It has many restrictions - almost no animations at all, plus it may be misleading for developers to use it.
If you want to have a "restricted" Splash screen then go with the API, but If you want to develop a good, custom Splash screen then just do not use word "splash" in the activity and that's all regarding the question.

Comment: @Pietrek If you have used a "splash activity" in a "legal" way you never had animations. It's just an activity with an image. The new Splash screens can use animations.

Answer (score 60):

Just change the name, without using "splash" in it.

Comment: Why minus? My suggestion does the job and answers the question. There is better approach for Android 12 and above ("better" is doubtful), but that was not the question.

Comment: You're right @Pietrek

Comment: You're right my man

Comment: Yes, its works.

Comment: Super!! 2 Upvotes from my side.

Comment: Smarter than Android's solution man! they try just to make our lives harder

Answer (score 11):

Starting in Android 12, the SplashScreen API enables a new app launch animation for all apps when running on a device with Android 12 or higher. This includes an into-app motion at launch, a splash screen showing your app icon, and a transition to your app itself.

TLDR; Android provides a new API for integrating SplashScreen.
First, remove the SplashScreen then follow below code block.

Add in build gradle
`implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-rc01'`

follow the below steps.

Define:

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/ed_colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_logo</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">200</item>
   <!-- Set the theme of the Activity that directly follows your splash screen. -->
    <!-- Required -->
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme</item>

</style>
```

Then in Manifest check and verify that you given `Theme.App.Starting`

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting" > 
    ...
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Finally, Don't forget to add.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        ...
```

Comment: For further reference, check: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

Answer (score 8):

You also can suppress it using this `@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")`:

```
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
}
```