# How do you create a different starting activity based on the user's Android version?

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

There's a new Splash Screen API they introduced for Android 12 and above: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

I want to apply it to Android versions that support it while keeping the old splash screen method for older Android version. In older Android versions the way to do a splash screen was to create a separate activity called SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And set it as the main launchpoint in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

So I want SplashActivity to exist only for APIs lower than 31 and I want to use the newer Splash Screen method on APIs 31 and higher. Is it possible to create different manifests per API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32822924/2827025

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splash Screen Compat library. Check the migration guide [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate)

Comment: Not very sure what to do. "If your existing splash screen Activity is primarily used for routing, consider ways to remove it; for example, you might directly link to the actual activity or move to a singular activity with subcomponents" What does this mean?

Comment: The top answer here says the new API can be used on older versions as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68803031/getting-warning-application-should-not-provide-its-own-splash-screen-in-android
But nobody explains how!